# Android WebView: How to Load links faster?

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView full of images, videos & gifs. When the WebView is loading and user clicks on any links on the WebView it don't open immediately. Instead it loads all the contents on the WebView and then loads the clicked link.

Is there any way to stop loading remaining content as soon as any link is clicked on the WebView and open the clicked link ASAP?

Comment: I don't think so . If links are handled inside `WebView` then this will happen as you said your page is quite heavy. You can do one thing during loading make `WebView` as invisible and make it visible after load complete .

Comment: @ADM that's quite inconvenient. Hiding the WebView isn't going to help. Users won't like to wait 5+ seconds seeing the loading screen.

Comment: Yeah . That's a disadvantage of this approach. Anyway this was my concern . Wait for a better answer.